# String not matching in shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to match two strings (IpAddress) as below. But it's not matching.

```
i=192.168.2.29
ipCheckInConfig="SG_1=192.168.2.24,192.168.2.29
> SG_2=192.168.2.20,192.168.2.23,192.168.2.31"

if echo "$i" | egrep -q "$ipCheckInConfig" ; then
    echo "Matched"
else
    echo "Not Matched"      
fi
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: The pattern is passed as a parameter, and the input is passed via standard input;  you have them reversed.

Comment: What Tim said...and the pattern you're looking for is bigger than the input string you're giving to `egrep`, so of course it can't find the big string in the little one.  You need to echo the long string and search for the short one.  Or use the built-in regex operator if your shell is `bash` — the Unix and Shell tags don't make that a slam-dunk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call egrep for that. Use bash's internal regex capabilities:

```
if [[ "$ipCheckInConfig" =~ $i ]]; then
    echo "Matched"
else
    echo "Not Matched"      
fi
```

Comment: Strictly, the question isn't tagged 'bash' and not all shells have the `bash` regex function.

Comment: Oh sorry for overlooking that fact. user2531569: Are you using bash by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Yes i am using Bash only.

Comment: If you're using BASH then my suggested answer should work fine.